# How can I recover an unallocated Ubuntu-Installation?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, unallocated

I use Ubuntu as my main OS and Windows for gaming (dual boot). After I reinstalled Windows, it has, as expected, overwritten grub. I restored grub in similar situations countless times using a live-cd (chroot, reinstalling grub etc.).
However this time, my old ubuntu partition is unallocated and therefore, cannot be mounted. Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: I followed the steps that were described for Testdisk. The lost partition was found, I pressed "write" as described and rebooted. Now all my partitions are gone and the whole disk is "unallocated"... this will be a long night I guess.

Comment: @GertrudeMauzikowski You always want to make a backup of whatever you're recovering, and you should use testdisk to recover the files  to a new partition on a separate disk so that you don't corrupt anythgin and you recover all you can.